# How to get Google Page Rank for a site hosted Blog

Tags: google, google-search-console, pagerank, google-ranking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is PageRank and how do I get it?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15/what-is-pagerank-and-how-do-i-get-it)

I am blogging since last june and got alxea rank for my site many days before... But I still dont get it that how to get Google PageRank for my site hosted on Google Blogger ?

Comment: FYI, your site gives a `403 Forbidden` error right now. Also, doing a `site:` search for your domain shows that, while Google has indexed some of your pages, they all have the same meta description, thus search snippet. You probably want to switch to a CMS that lets you specify unique meta descriptions for each page. Also, for some reason the SERP thumbnail of each page is some cpanel webhost with a dragon on their homepage. Lastly, you might try using coherent alt text for your article images instead of just a list of keywords, which might be misinterpreted as keyword stuffing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Analytic to get the page ranks and get the info of your site visitors.